# detect if any wireless device connected

Tags: networking, wifi

Actually, I want to try to protect a server against wireless connections.

I try to get an alert when someone plug a wireless device to my server.

Is there a way to detect this, or is a software can alert me when my network is changed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, your question does not make much sense in it's current form - could you clarify what you mean? Do you want to be able to tell when a machine is connected to a wireless laptop that is not being broadcast by a router or access point?

Comment: Seriously, you need to sit down and really clarify all the details of your question. What is a wireless modem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Can I ask why you need to specifically detect rogue wireless devices? Why have people got physical access to the server and why are you only concerned about wireless devices, I'd be far more worried about a myriad of other things people could plug in and do to a physical machine

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect rogue WIFI routers on a network?](http://serverfault.com/questions/8192/how-to-detect-rogue-wifi-routers-on-a-network)

Answer (score 2):

No, without wireless hardware you have no way of detecting any other wireless devices.

Additionally, I don't believe there is such as a device as a wireless modem.

Comment: I think the 3G dongles you connect to your laptop could be classed as a wireless modem but not really on-topic.

Comment: @boburob Margnially, I suppose they're one of the few modern devices that actually identify as modems. That said, I'd class them as "3G Modems" - I've never heard anyone referring to GSM and its ilk as "Wireless"